# Distribution Certificate in xCode Organizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Can I have more than one Distribution Certificate?  I am developing an app but the current certificate was not created by me and is for another app.  That app and cert was done by someone else who is no longer here.

I downloaded the vert, but in the organizer it tells me, Valid signing identity not found.

What am I to do?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is shown, because a valid Signing Identity is not found. The Apple Documentation clearly [describes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH7-SW17) how to export/import it. You should ask the certificate's creator to export his own copy of the certificate (because it can't be re-downloaded from the iOS Dev Center), then you can import and use it.

Comment: Ok, so I probably am restating what you said, but just to be clear.  If I go back to the computer that generated the Distribution Certificate and have that person export the certificate and the take the files and import into my keychain then I should be able to use it.  Is that correct?  I am assuming I need the private key.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need the public/private key and the certificate itself. Xcode makes the importing/exporting super easy (see the description in the documentation), but you can do it manually using Keychain Access. I recommend the former.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between certificates and provisioning profiles.

Certificates are associated per account while provisioning profiles are for individual apps under each account.

If you are working with multiple iTunes / Apple Developer accounts, then yes you should have a certificate for each of those accounts installed in your keychain.

And assuming your app has it's own application (bundle) ID, you need to have a provisioning profile for each of the apps you're developing under that account.  There are different provisioning profiles for distributing ADHOC builds and the Store build that gets uploaded for review by Apple.

It sounds like you need to start with just getting the certificate for the account you want to work with, then the provisioning profile.